# Isn't NSDecimalNumber supposed to be able to do base-10 arithmetic?

Tags: ios, math, floating-point, nsdecimalnumber

```
NSDecimalNumber *minVal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.0"];
NSDecimalNumber *maxVal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"111.1"];
NSDecimalNumber *valRange = [maxVal decimalNumberBySubtracting:minVal];
CGFloat floatRange = [valRange floatValue];
NSLog(@"%f", floatRange); //prints 111.099998
```

Isn't `NSDecimalNumber` supposed to be able to do base-10 arithmetic correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just doing that `CGFloat aNumber = 111.1;` shows as `111.099998` in the debugger, **even before any operation has been performed on it**. Therefore the precision is lost right when it is assigned to the less precise data type, regardless of any arithmetic operations occurring later.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `NSDecimalNumber` operates in base-10, but `CGFloat` doesn't.

Comment: I'm not performing any arithmetic operation on `CGFloat`

Comment: no, but you are getting the float value and logging as a float. Float does not have the capacity to display certain exact numbers. Obviously 111.100000 is one of them

Comment: `floatValue` does (btw, you should probably use `doubleValue` instead as it's the preferred method in [`NSDecimalNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

Comment: From Apple's documentation: doubleValue
"Returns the **approximate** value of the receiver as a double."

Comment: ok, just doing that `CGFloat aNumber = 111.1;` shows as `111.099998` in the debugger even before any operation has been performed on it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `NSDecimalNumber` is base-10.

Converting to a floating point type will can loose accuracy. In their case since the example just used `NSLog` just `NSLog` the `NSDecimalNumber`:

```
NSDecimalNumber *minVal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.0"];
NSDecimalNumber *maxVal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"111.1"];
NSDecimalNumber *valRange = [maxVal decimalNumberBySubtracting:minVal];
CGFloat floatRange = [valRange floatValue];
NSLog(@"floatRange: %f", floatRange);
NSLog(@"valRange: %@", valRange);
```

NSLog output:

```
floatRange: 111.099998
valRange: 111.1
```